# Warcraft 3 obtain phat lewt in early Orc stages

Tags: warcraft-3

In the early Orc stages in Warcraft 3 I recall there being a chest on a small island that is inaccessible.  This chest is an item called phat lewt.  My question is how do I go about obtaining this item and what is its value in the game?  I understand the concept of receiving phat lewt, just wanted to know what it is in WC3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That island is inaccessible even once you reveal it with a cheat, so there's no way to reach the chest in the campaign.

According to [WoWWiki](http://www.wowwiki.com/Phat_Lewt), it's valued at 500 gold, and it's used in practice as a filler item for NPC heroes in the campaign while not having any other utility at all:

> In practice, Phat Lewt is used throughout the campaign as an "inventory slot filler" for non-player heroes. Phat Lewt is flagged as the most powerful item in the game despite not actually doing anything, thus AI heroes will never drop the item. Many heroes have 1 to 6 Phat Lewts in their inventories throughout the campaign, but they are always invisible to players.

Comment: that is depressing.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: You can always make a custom map :P

Answer (score 0):

You can get Phat Lewt with World Editor:

1. Open World Editor
2. Click "Layer" then "Units"
3. Click "Player 1 Red"
4. Click Items
5. Click "Any Class"
6. Click "Campaign"
7. In there you will find the Phat Lewt!

Testing:

1. Place it on the map to test it.
2. Place 1 hero then Press "Cltrl+F9"
3. It's done!

Comment: Is there any way to obtain it in the campaign?

Comment: @Sadly Not: I see what you did there.